# Deploying Integrity CI to subdirectory on Nginx and Unicorn

Tags: nginx, sinatra, unicorn

I am trying to deploy [Integrity continuous integration server](http://integrity.github.com) to a subdirectory (or base URL). That is, I'd like to host it at a URL like http://dev.example.com/integrity/ rather than http://integrity.example.com.

I'm using Unicorn and Nginx. My Nginx configuration:

```
upstream integrity {
    server unix:/home/integrity_ci/integrity/tmp/sockets/integrity.socket;
}

server {
    server_name dev.example.com;
    location /integrity {
        proxy_pass http://integrity;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
   }
}
```

Going to http://dev.example.com/integrity/ brings up the Integrity 404 (rather than the Nginx 404 page), so the Nginx configuration looks to be correct. But how do I configure Unicorn/Integrity to recognize /integrity as the application root?

Adding a rewrite rule to Nginx won't work, because Integrity will construct URLs with `/` rather that `/integrity`, so CSS, JavaScript, and links will be broken.

Integrity is a Sinatra application, so perhaps there is a standard way to do this.

Comment: It looks like the base URL comes from `request.script_name`. See ways to set this using fastCGI, but how do I set it with Unicorn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `config.ru`, replace:

```
run Integrity.app
```

with:

```
map ('/integrity') { run Integrity.app }
```